# How do you fix error using WebServer server.on() for ESP32 using CLion/PlatformIO?

Tags: c++, webserver, esp32

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://lastminuteengineers.com/esp32-dht11-dht22-web-server-tutorial/) to learn how to make a web server for an engineering final project. I copied the code as originally provided, but the code had errors because it could not find the functions defined at the end, so I reordered them to be above. Then a new error showed up.

The code works fine using Arduino IDE with ESP32 board manager.
I need it to work using CLion though. I have Arduino Support, Ini, and PlatformIO for Clion plugins installed.

Error shows up on line 37, as red line under "handle_OnConnect". Only highlights the first use of the defined functions, eg. if handle_OnConnect is removed, then just handle_led1on becomes the error.

Error information:

In template: no matching function for call to 'operator new'

Location: ~/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa32/xtensa-esp32-elf/include/c++/5.2.0/functional

in instantiation of member function 'std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<void (*)()>::_M_init_functor' requested here

in instantiation of member function 'std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<void (*)()>::_M_init_functor' requested here

in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::function<void ()>::function<void (*)(), void>' requested here

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebServer.h>

/* Put your SSID & Password */
const char* ssid = "ESP32";  // Enter SSID here
const char* password = "12345678";  //Enter Password here

/* Put IP Address details */
IPAddress local_ip(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress gateway(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);

WebServer server(80);

uint8_t LED1pin = 2;
bool LED1status = LOW;

uint8_t LED2pin = 4;
bool LED2status = LOW;

void handle_OnConnect();
void handle_led1on();
void handle_led1off();
void handle_led2on();
void handle_led2off();
void handle_NotFound();

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    pinMode(LED1pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED2pin, OUTPUT);

    WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
    WiFi.softAPConfig(local_ip, gateway, subnet);
    delay(100);

    server.on("/", handle_OnConnect);
    server.on("/led1on", handle_led1on);
    server.on("/led1off", handle_led1off);
    server.on("/led2on", handle_led2on);
    server.on("/led2off", handle_led2off);
    server.onNotFound(handle_NotFound);

    server.begin();
    Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}
void loop() {
    server.handleClient();
    if(LED1status)
    {digitalWrite(LED1pin, HIGH);}
    else
    {digitalWrite(LED1pin, LOW);}

    if(LED2status)
    {digitalWrite(LED2pin, HIGH);}
    else
    {digitalWrite(LED2pin, LOW);}
}

String SendHTML(uint8_t led1stat,uint8_t led2stat){
    String ptr = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html>\n";
    ptr +="<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\">\n";
    ptr +="<title>LED Control</title>\n";
    ptr +="<style>html { font-family: Helvetica; display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;}\n";
    ptr +="body{margin-top: 50px;} h1 {color: #444444;margin: 50px auto 30px;} h3 {color: #444444;margin-bottom: 50px;}\n";
    ptr +=".button {display: block;width: 80px;background-color: #3498db;border: none;color: white;padding: 13px 30px;text-decoration: none;font-size: 25px;margin: 0px auto 35px;cursor: pointer;border-radius: 4px;}\n";
    ptr +=".button-on {background-color: #3498db;}\n";
    ptr +=".button-on:active {background-color: #2980b9;}\n";
    ptr +=".button-off {background-color: #34495e;}\n";
    ptr +=".button-off:active {background-color: #2c3e50;}\n";
    ptr +="p {font-size: 14px;color: #888;margin-bottom: 10px;}\n";
    ptr +="</style>\n";
    ptr +="</head>\n";
    ptr +="<body>\n";
    ptr +="<h1>ESP32 Web Server</h1>\n";
    ptr +="<h3>Using Access Point(AP) Mode</h3>\n";

    if(led1stat)
    {ptr +="<p>LED1 Status: ON</p><a class=\"button button-off\" href=\"/led1off\">OFF</a>\n";}
    else
    {ptr +="<p>LED1 Status: OFF</p><a class=\"button button-on\" href=\"/led1on\">ON</a>\n";}

    if(led2stat)
    {ptr +="<p>LED2 Status: ON</p><a class=\"button button-off\" href=\"/led2off\">OFF</a>\n";}
    else
    {ptr +="<p>LED2 Status: OFF</p><a class=\"button button-on\" href=\"/led2on\">ON</a>\n";}

    ptr +="</body>\n";
    ptr +="</html>\n";
    return ptr;
}

void handle_OnConnect() {
    LED1status = LOW;
    LED2status = LOW;
    Serial.println("GPIO4 Status: OFF | GPIO5 Status: OFF");
    server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(LED1status,LED2status));
}

void handle_led1on() {
    LED1status = HIGH;
    Serial.println("GPIO4 Status: ON");
    server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(true,LED2status));
}

void handle_led1off() {
    LED1status = LOW;
    Serial.println("GPIO4 Status: OFF");
    server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(false,LED2status));
}

void handle_led2on() {
    LED2status = HIGH;
    Serial.println("GPIO5 Status: ON");
    server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(LED1status,true));
}

void handle_led2off() {
    LED2status = LOW;
    Serial.println("GPIO5 Status: OFF");
    server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(LED1status,false));
}

void handle_NotFound(){
    server.send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}
```

Comment: Either there is the error you're asking about or the code builds. If that error is happening, the code is not building. And when I compile your code, I don't get that error, so I'd venture that something else is happening.

Comment: I have the same "error" shown in the IDE. The code builds fine and runs until the point where `.on([](){})` is called where it crashes.